# Raspberry Pi, WinSCP "Permission Denied", have tried everything

Tags: networking, ftp, raspberry-pi, winscp

I keep getting "Permission denied" when trying to edit files, and I've tried everything I've googled to try and fix this. [Here](https://prnt.sc/ksyzpm) is a picture of the problem I'm referring to. Here's what I know:

1) I've used touch on a specific file in the directory I'm wanting to edit, and I did not get a "Permission denied response" - see [this image](https://prnt.sc/ksyyud)

2) The group does have full access to the files, and my account is a member of that group.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can do, thanks.

Comment: Are you using `andrewh` account in WinSCP? Can you post a log file?

Answer (score 0):

May be stupid, but I tried editing files while they were in the Pi. Transferring files back and forth were fine though.